# How to generate real time graph from database using JSP and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to generate graph/charts of **types of child abuse** and the **number of respective cases** (refer image of static graph given on serial number 4)from the database using JSP in eclipse. I have connected JSP  page to the database but i was unable to generate realtime graph. Help me how to do so. Below are the codes of JSP , Javascript and the image of database table.

```
1. JSP Code

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@page import = "java.sql.*" %>
 
<%


Connection connection;

PreparedStatement statement;

ResultSet result;

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/pbl","root","");

String fetchData = "SELECT * from abuses";

Statement st = connection.createStatement();

result = st.executeQuery(fetchData);

%> 
    
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <title>Graphs Real-time</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="sb-nav-fixed">

            <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
                <main>
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <h1 class="mt-4">Charts</h1>
                        <ol class="breadcrumb mb-4">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Charts</li>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="card mb-4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card mb-4">
                            <div class="card-header">
                                <i class="fas fa-chart-area mr-1"></i>
                                Area Chart
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-body"><canvas id="myAreaChart" width="100%" height="30"></canvas></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="card mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                        <i class="fas fa-chart-bar mr-1"></i>
                                        Bar Chart
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body"><canvas id="myBarChart" width="100%" height="50"></canvas></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="card mb-4">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                        <i class="fas fa-chart-pie mr-1"></i>
                                        Pie Chart
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body"><canvas id="myPieChart" width="100%" height="50"></canvas></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="assets/demo/chart-area-demo.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/demo/chart-bar-demo.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/demo/chart-pie-demo.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

2. Javascript Code

```
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = '-apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#292b2c';
var ctx = document.getElementById("myAreaChart");
var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Physical Abuse", "Sexual Abuse", "Verbal/Emotional Abuse", "Mental/Psychological Abuse", "Others"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Sessions",
      lineTension: 0.3,
      backgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,0.2)",
      borderColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
      pointRadius: 5,
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
      pointBorderColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0.8)",
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(2,117,216,1)",
      pointHitRadius: 50,
      pointBorderWidth: 2,
      data: [2, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    }],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        time: {
          unit: 'date'
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        ticks: {
          maxTicksLimit: 7
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          min: 0,
          max: 20,
          maxTicksLimit: 5
        },
        gridLines: {
          color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .125)",
        }
      }],
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
});
```

3. Database :
   [image: This is a pic of the database]
4. Static Graph for your reference

[This is a static image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e98sI.png)